# Canon EOS T2i 35-55 mm lens. Won't autofocus

Tags: canon, autofocus, troubleshooting

Actually it WILL autofocus if I force adjust focus by hand beyond subject.  It then adjusts itself to focus.  If the lens is focused in front of the subject, it will not autofocus.  Bad servo in the lens?

Comment: I've never heard of an EOS EF 35-55mm lens. What lens are you actually referring to?

Comment: If you are forcing manual focus on a non *FTM focus* lens when the switch is set to *AF*, you have probably damaged the focus mechanism. Maybe the servo, but more likely the linkage at some point.

Answer (score 1):

If you think the motor is only working in one direction, you might try to test the theory by focusing in live mode.  If it's like mine, it will usually go back and forth to home in on the sharpest focus (using contrast rather than phase detection), so if the motor is only working in one direction it will probably not be able to focus in live mode.

Of course, if you have any access to a different camera, you could double check it on another camera to make sure the problem is in the lens.  In any case, you'll probably need to send it in for analysis/repair.